# Laravel Tests assertEquals says Target class [request] does not exist

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, laravel-9

I am writing a test in Laravel like this (only the relevant part):

```
namespace Tests\Feature\Response;

use App\Models\Customer;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ResponseTest extends TestCase
{
    protected $customer;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->customer = Customer::factory()->enabled()->create();
    }

    public function testJson(): void
    {
        $responseData = (object) ['code' => 'NOT OK'];

        // Test its response
        $this->assertEquals('OK', $responseData->code, 'response data did not respond OK');
    }
}
```

But instead of giving me the message "response data did not respond OK" it responds with "Target class [request] does not exist".

The relevant part of the factory look like this:

```
public function enabled()
{
    return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
        return [
            'enabled' => 1
        ];
    });
}
```

The relevant part of the `Customer` Model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    $request = request();
}
```

Oddly enough: when I don't use the state "enabled()" the problem does not occure. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: You can try switching it to `return $this->state(['enabled' => 1]);`, but can you share the full stack trace? We need to see who is trying to instantiate `request` class

Comment: @matiaslauriti I don't know how how to share the full stack trace because the code is not failing; it just doesn't do what its supposed to do. But I isolated the problem further more and I found out that the request() function calling in the boot of the Customer model is causing the problem. So I now included the relevant part of the Customer model in my question too.

Comment: I think '''request()``` doesn't exist in CLI mode.

Comment: and why do you need $request = request(); in your customer model? It's not good to create a dependency on a http context, when these are not here at all time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your issue is fairly obvious, you have `request` inside the `boot` function, when a request is not always available.

As another user stated, NEVER involve contexts that are specific, into broad systems, like a model. You can definitely use a model in a CLI or Job/Listener context, so you do not or could not have a `request` available...

And you are also just doing `$request = request();`, that does absolutely nothing. Delete the whole `boot` function, you do not need it at all (at least in the context/code you shared)